# How to make a list in Racket that you can iterate in the same order you add elements?

Tags: list, linked-list, scheme, racket, idioms

It's a pretty common programming use case to build up a list of things and then later to need to iterate over the list in the same order that you added to the list. A simple example may be recording compiler errors and then printing them for the user. You want the errors that were earlier in the source code, that you parsed first, to be the ones that are printed first to the screen.

But in Lisp/Scheme/Racket lists only have a head pointer, without a tail pointer. This means you can only cheaply add elements to the beginning, and you can only cheaply iterate the elements in reverse of the order that you added them. In learning Racket I've been seeing an awful lot of code that builds a list and then later iterates over `(reverse the-list)`. In practice for plenty of applications this should be fine, but it seems a little silly to have to add an extra N operations to your algorithm every time this comes up.

Is there a standard-idiom/most-common-solution for solving this problem? I can always roll my own list type with a tail pointer, or reimplement C++ std::vector on top of Racket's mutable vectors, but this seems common enough that there should be an already established best practice for what to do.

Comment: I don’t think this is a commonly-used library, so take this suggestion with a grain of salt, but the [pvector](http://docs.racket-lang.org/pvector/index.html) library implements a *functional* data structure that has efficient appends. Disclaimer: I am the author of that library.

Comment: Reversing the a list is idiomatic Scheme. Implementing a queue as a list with a tail pointer is idiomatic Scheme. The question boils down to a request for a idiomatic Scheme that is not idiomatic Scheme based on an opinion that the idioms are silly. The question is not about an actual problem. It contains no code. Voting to close.

Comment: @benrudgers I didn't object to having a queue with implemented as a list of the tail pointer, I was just saying that I figured I was doing it wrong if I was implementing it myself, since I figure this should be a pretty common need.

Comment: For most applications, not reversing the list is likely to be non-idiomatic. Writing one's own queue is the idiomatic alternative. I don't see any code or an actual problem to be solved, just a statement of opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot think of any way of doing it with plain Racket's lists.

There is an efficient alternative, take a look at Racket's Queues: https://docs.racket-lang.org/functional-data-structures/Queues.html

The Banker's Queue provides amortized O(1) time for enqueue, head and tail, which according to your use case, are the functions you need.

**Update:** There are several queues that work for your scenario, one another that is mentioned by @ben-rudgers in the comments is the Imperative Queue: https://docs.racket-lang.org/data/Imperative_Queues.html

That one also provides constant time for `enqueue!` and `dequeue!`.

Comment: Because this question is tagged 'scheme' and 'idiom' and 'racket', suggesting a library for another language (typed-racket) does not seem particularly well aligned. Not that there's anything wrong with the library. I think the problem is in the question.

Comment: I don't get your point very well, as this Typed Racket library is usable in plain Racket.

Comment: The imperative queue is more idiomatic and less dependent on a particular Scheme implementation (though the actual implementation has a lot #racket dependencies). https://docs.racket-lang.org/data/Imperative_Queues.html?q=data%2Fqueue Of course, reversing a list is still the most idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely familiar with the std::vector in C++, but I believe Racket's growable vectors are fairly similar, and could be used for this. They can be imported from the data-lib package by adding `(require data/gvector)`: https://docs.racket-lang.org/data/gvector.html

Comment: this actually looks exactly like std::vector, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

### You know what they say

> The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time
>   worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times;
>   premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of
>   it) in programming.

By 'they' I mean Donald Knuth and Tony Hoare.

### Comparing Queue Implementations

The code below runs `#lang racket`'s Bankers' Queue, Imperative Queue, and a plain old list that gets reversed. That's the sequence in which they are run. Each is run inside a timing function. A `'major` garbage collection is done outside the timing function before each is run.

```
#lang racket
(require data/queue) ;; the imperative queue
(require (rename-in pfds/queue/bankers
                    (queue->list bq2list)))
(define (run)
  (writeln "bankers' queue for 10,000")
  (writeln "imperative queue for 1,000,000")
  (writeln "reversed list for 1,000,00")

  (collect-garbage 'major)

  ;; bankers' queue
  (time 
   (define q (queue))
   (for ((i (range 10000)))
     (enqueue i q))
   (bq2list q)
   'done)

  (collect-garbage 'major)

  ;; imperative queue
  (time 
   (define q (make-queue))
   (for ((i (range 1000000)))
     (enqueue! q i))
   (queue->list q))

  (collect-garbage 'major)

  ;; reversed list
  (time
   (define q
     (for/list ((i (range 1000000)))
       i))
   (reverse q))
  'done)

(run)
```

### Typical Output

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 6.6 [3m].
Language: racket, with debugging; memory limit: 1024 MB.
"bankers' queue for 10,000"
"imperative queue for 1,000,000"
"reversed list for 1,000,00"
cpu time: 1748 real time: 1752 gc time: 1000
cpu time: 664 real time: 664 gc time: 272
cpu time: 436 real time: 436 gc time: 180
'done
> (run)
"bankers' queue for 10,000"
"imperative queue for 1,000,000"
"reversed list for 1,000,00"
cpu time: 752 real time: 754 gc time: 8
cpu time: 660 real time: 661 gc time: 248
cpu time: 456 real time: 460 gc time: 192
'done
> (run)
"bankers' queue for 10,000"
"imperative queue for 1,000,000"
"reversed list for 1,000,00"
cpu time: 776 real time: 779 gc time: 40
cpu time: 692 real time: 693 gc time: 256
cpu time: 456 real time: 458 gc time: 184
'done
>
```

### Interpeting the Results

1. An idiomatic plain old reversed list tends to be fastest [at least in this naive implementation]. Not particularly surprising due to the reduced book-keeping and doing the expected (i.e. idiomatic) thing.
2. The imperative queue is about the same speed as a naive list. Racket's implementation uses `struct`'s. Since these are the basic building blocks for higher level types in the Racket ecosystem, it's not surprising for a data structure built upon them to be performant. If queue semantics are important, the queue abstraction is probably worth running a bit slower.
3. Sometimes I get impatient when programming, I've heard it's a virtue, if reducing the number of iterations of Bankers' Queue from a million to ten thousand due to my impatience constitutes a virtuous act, then maybe there's anecdotal evidence that it is. Anyway, Bankers' Queue ran about two orders of magnitude more slowly than either of the others. Of course, speed is just one measure of performance. Thread safety is another and the speed tradeoff may be worth it.

Comment: These results are interesting but they are more an indictment of the quality of the racket compiler than anything else. There is no good reason at the algorithmic level or at the assembly level for an algorithm that requires an extra iteration over all of the data to perform better. I tried adding gvector to your benchmark and it does worse than the imperative queue -- seeing as it should be using contiguous cache friendly memory and thus should slaughter a list, I can only conclude that the implementation is crazy inefficient.

Comment: @JosephGarvin The period of the Earth's orbit around the Sun is O(1). It still takes a year.. Bubble sorting ten elements is O(n^2) and finishes in significantly less time. That's the way Big Oh works. As mentioned in my answer, Racket's Bankers' Queue is thread safe and might be suitable in a distributed environment where network latency or the rate at which users press keys determine the how fast the implementation needs to be. There's no silver bullet.

Comment: It's not the way CPUs work -- traversing the data in an extra time and storing it without contiguity only beats contiguous data that traverses the data once if you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @JosephGarvin   CPU != computer

Comment: The pfds queues are *immutable* data types; unlike the other two, the banker's queue benchmark is timing adding a single element to an empty queue, and converting an empty queue to a list. And I have no idea why you're reversing the `for/list` version; that gives the numbers in reverse order of the imperative queue version.